# How to optimize a python script which runs for 4**k times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

Programming language: Python 3.4

I have written a program for the Bioinformatics 1 course from Coursera. The program is working all right, but is **very slow for large datasets**. I guess, it is because the loop is running for 4**k times, where k is the length of the sub-string that is passed into the function.
Input: Strings *Text* and *Pattern* along with an integer *d*.
Output: All starting positions where *Pattern* appears as a substring of Text with at most *d* mismatches.

This is my code:

```
def MotifCount(string1, substring, d):
    k = 4 ** (len(substring))
    codeArray = list(itertools.product(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'], repeat=len(substring)))
    for i in range(k):
        codeArray2 = ''.join(list(codeArray[i]))
        HammingValue = HammingDistance(codeArray2, substring)
        if HammingValue <= d:
            for j in range(len(string1)):
                if(string1.find(codeArray2, j) == j):
                    print(j)



def HammingDistance(string_1, string_2):
    length_1 = len(string_1)
    length_2 = len(string_2)
    count = 0
    for i in range(length_1):
        if string_1[i] != string_2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

**Sample Input:**

```
CGCCCGAATCCAGAACGCATTCCCATATTTCGGGACCACTGGCCTCCACGGTACGGACGTCAATCAAAT
ATTCTGGA
3
```

**Output:**

```
6 7 26 27
```

I want to optimize this code for bigger data sets. Is there any way to reduce the run time of the code?

Comment: Your solution looks like a brute force method. Creating exponentially many patterns and then check all of them can never efficient. I think you have to switch to another algorithm. I am not sure what is the best algorithm here, but a simplified version of a local sequence alignment will probably already speed things up drastically.

Comment: Thanks. I am learning the subject now. I will look it up. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools

def HammingDistance(string_1, string_2):
    assert len(string_1) == len(string_2)
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(string_1, string_2))

def MotifCount(string1, substring, d):
    for i in range(len(string1) - len(substring) + 1):
        if HammingDistance(string1[i:i+len(substring)], substring) <= d:
            print(i)

MotifCount("CGCCCGAATCCAGAACGCATTCCCATATTTCGGGACCACTGGCCTCCACGGTACGGACGTCAATCAAAT", "ATTCTGGA", 3)
```

It gives:

```
6
7
26
27
```

Quickly.

Comment: The use of `xrange` instead of `range` will also give you a small improvement, especially if the lengths are large.

Comment: @MartinEvans, this only applies to python2, the question is about python3.4.

Comment: I think instead of `range(len(string1) - len(substring))` it should be `range(len(string1) - len(substring)+1)`, note the `+1` because the upper bound is exclusive and the last index you want the pattern to start is `len(string1) - len(substring)`.

Comment: @halex You are right, thank you for your notice. Fixed.

Comment: @dlask : The program worked nicely. But there are some aspects of the program that I did not understand. For example:
return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(string_1, string_2))
And can you explain the algorithm you used. i mean, you did not compare them so many times. I kind of, did not understand what exactly you did. (I am sorry, but am totally new to Python) :)

Comment: You can play with individual expressions such as `zip("abc", "def")` and see what happens. About the algorithm: I move `substring` along the `string1` and calculate the Hamming distance at each position. When it's lower than the specified limit I print the current position.